# How to alter output or filter output to display what you want

Tags: python, json

This is the code that displays output that I would like to alter:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


with open('users.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

ordered_data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda k: -k[1]['balance']))

first = ordered_data.popitem(last=False)
print(first)
```

Ouput:

```
('<@!702221444796383454>', {'balance': 90})
```

I would like the code to output this instead:

```
702221444796383454 90
```

I have tried `"".join()` and I tried googling things to try and find a solution but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the. variable first you can extract the bits of information you want into a string, and if the first part is always in that format you can splice it up.

```
output =f"{first[0][3:-1]} {first[1]['balance']}"
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the `popitem` returns a **tuple**.

('<@!702221444796383454>', {'balance': 90}) is the tuple returned by `popitem` in your case. And the returned tuple is stored in the variable "first".

So `first[0]` will return the first element and `first[1]` will return the second element.

Then tweak them accordingly, in the way you want.